Alt+Space shortcut doesn't open system menu anymore
Seen a bunch of questions/answers saying it's because of PowerToys, it isn't my case.
Tried restarting the computer, closing every single program but still nothing.
Using Microsoft Keyboard Diagnostics (mskey.exe), indeed the key combination do work:

Any clues are more than welcome.

Works for me. Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and then sfc /scannow.

I found the cause, posted an answer.

another common culprit nowadays is Windows Powertoys

Yes I know, but for once, it wasn't at fault! :D

Found the culprit:

Samsung Magician (once again...)

When it is set to start automatically, Alt-Space stops working, when started manually it doesn't.

I can confirm that this was the cause, and the fix, for my own case of this bug.
